# Importing an own python file, Class not defined

Tags: python

I have created the following Classses in a file called my_class.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # do something

class MyClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # do something
```

When I import that module I get this:

```
>>> import my_class
>>> a = MyClassA()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MyClassA' is not defined
```

If I do:

```
from my_class import MyClassA
```

it works... is there a way I can import all the classes (modules) within that file if there were more and without using the "from X import Y" statement?

Comment: Use `from my_class import *`

Comment: Wildcard imports are not recommended.  Use `my_class.MyClassA`

Comment: `from my_class import *` but Python Style Guides suggest to explicitly import all the needed objects with inline syntax: `from my_class import MyClassA, MyClassB`

Comment: Or import just the module: `import my_class`, then use `a = my_class.MyClassA`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my_class is the module you are importing. Syntax-wise the classes, variables, and so on defined in my_class.py are attributes of the imported module. Use:

```
import my_class

ca = my_class.MyClassA()
```

or if you want to access my_class often, you can change the identifier on import:

```
import my_class as mc

ca = mc.MyClassA()
```

This is the most pythonic way iirc. On a further note:

```
from my_class import MyClassA

ca = MyClassA()
```

is basically the same as:

```
import my_class
MyClassA = my_class.MyClassA

ca = MyClassA()
```

In both variants my_class will be pre compiled and imported. The [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) might help as well.

Comment: You can change the first line to `import my_class` without any error.

Comment: Oops, I obviously brainfarted. Now it is correct

Comment: I would say: 

    import my_class as mc
    a = mc.MyClassA()

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell python that `MyClassA` is in `my_class`.

```
>>> import my_class
>>> a = myclass.MyClassA()
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, is this more recommended than doing "from my_class import MyClassA"?

Comment: This prevents name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

When you have referenced MyClassA Python will not recognise it as you have defined it outside of the current file, to tell it where to look you need to reference it using the file name in which it was defined like so: `a = my_class.MyClassA()`.
If you don't want to have to write out `my_class.example` every time you reference a variable from that file you can use `import my_class as mc` this means that you can shorten your code as now you can use `a = mc.MyClassA()`. This is a preferable solution to universal imports (`from example import *`) as it clearly shows where the variable has come from, increasing readability, and avoids any possible conflicts between modules.